# How to overwrite a save value for same player name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Trying to get a functioning top scores class working. This is my current code. If i add more player objects the list gets larger and looks something like John[1] booboomcgoo[1] with the [1] being the number of games won. However, I'm stuck now because when the same player plays again I can't figure out how to replace the games won with a higher value by searching the text file for the string and if it matches one that was entered previous, then it increments gameswon by 1 value.

I'm not even sure if this approach is even possible or if my general approach to this problem is wrong. Any help is appreciated. PS I have commented out code that I will use later to display info on the screen, please ignore.

```
class display_top_scores():


        def __init__(self, players_name, gameswon):
                self.players_name = players_name
                self.gameswon = gameswon
                self.scores_list = []
                self.times_won = []

        def show_scores(self):
                text_file = open("topscores.txt", "w+")
                self.scores_list.append(self.players_name)
                text_file.writelines(self.scores_list)

                #print(scores_list)

                self.times_won.append(self.gameswon)
                s = str(self.times_won)
                text_file.writelines(s)
                text_file.close()
                text_file = open("topscores.txt", "r+")
                for line in text_file:
                    print(line)

                #print(times_won)
                #print("I am here1")
                #font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 30)
                #print("I am here2")
                #screen.blit(menu_background, [0, 0])
                #print("Iam here3")
##                textonscreen = drawText('Here are the top scores for easy mode:', font, screen, 600, 400, colors.Colors.wheat)
##                #print("Iam here4")
##                textonscreen.draw_menu_text()
##                #print("Iam here5")
##                pygame.display.update()
##                #print("Iam here6")
##                textonscreen = drawText('%s has won %d times.' % (self.players_name, self.gameswon), font, screen, 600, 450, colors.Colors.wheat)
##                #print("Iam here4")
##                textonscreen.draw_menu_text()
##                #print("Iam here5")
##                pygame.display.update()
##                #print("Iam here6")


players_name = "boboomcgoo"
showscore = display_top_scores(players_name, 1)
showscore.show_scores()

players_name = "John"
showscore = display_top_scores(players_name, 1)
showscore.show_scores()

players_name = "booboomcgoo"
showscore = display_top_scores(players_name, 1)
showscore.show_scores()
```

Comment: Instead of keeping lists and appending, you can maintain a `dict`. Then if a player name doesn't exist, add that player and their score. If they do exist, you can update their score.

Comment: How would you check a dict to see if a player name exists or not?

Comment: `if playername in myDict:`

Comment: I would use a dict instead of a list to store the scores and pickle the dict for disk persistence instead of a .txt

Comment: text_file = open("topscores.sav", "w+")
                
json.dump(self.states, text_file)

How do I append more dict's to the sav file? Each time I run this it replaces the json dump with the new one. I would like it to add rather than replace. Any input would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're incredibly constrained for storage space, you don't need to go in and edit the number of games played after each game. Instead, just add a log entry after each game. In the file, store an entry for each game's date, its rule set (if needed), its players, and its outcome. You could store this log as a JSON object (`import json`), a CSV row (`import csv`), an SQLite database (`import sqlite3`), or any of several other formats.

- Whenever a game is played, open the log file in append mode (`open(filename, 'a')`), write out the new result, and close the file. Append mode assures that records of old games won't get overwritten. Or in SQLite, `INSERT INTO` your log table.
- To calculate the win-loss record for a player or pair of players, open the log file in read mode, parse each game's record, and if the player names match what you expect, add one win or one loss. If scanning a large log causes the application to freeze momentarily, you might want to spawn a worker thread for this calculation (`import threading`, or `from concurrent import futures` in Python 3.2 or later) so that it doesn't block your event-handling thread. Or you might choose to just parse them all at once into a `list` and do various `sum` operations over this `list`. In fact, SQLite can do this for you with `SELECT SUM`.

Comment: That's a bit too much for what I really need.